# Make an iOS control look like controls from Settings

Tags: ios

Disclaimer: I'm new to iOS development.

I created a mock up using Keynotopia and now I want to actually build the UI (sample screenshot below). How do I build controls that look like the controls found in my mock? I see these designs used in other apps like Settings. Is this standard functionality within Xcode?

More specifically, the "controls" or "cells" that have the label text and cell value in the same space? So when the cell is clicked, a keyboard opens to change the text.

How do I place the ">" character at the right side of the cell? The effect I want to achieve is that the app moves another screen when clicked.

[image: Mock created in Keynotopia]

Comment: This is UITableview with Grouped style. and has     `cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailButton;`

Comment: It's a table view, but it looks substantially different in iOS7.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this tutorial. 
http://adeem.me/blog/2009/05/20/iphone-sdk-tutorial-part-3-grouped-uitableview/

or

http://nscookbook.com/2013/02/ios-programming-recipe-11-using-the-uitableview-part-ii/

And for you > and the corner you can achieve this in several ways

Put a UIImageView on you cell. Create small arrow and assign it to that image view. Since all your cells are of the same style you can easily achieve this by creating a prototype cell for your TableView.

Here is a tutorial for how to create your prototype cells

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/customizing-uitableview-cell/

or

http://eencae.wordpress.com/ios-tutorials/uikit/data-views/uitableview/custom-table-cell-prototypes/